# Why are the pressures in the Joule-Thompson effect the same before and after?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine, carnot-cycle

I understand the Joule-Thompson effect and the mathematics behind it that results in the Enthalpy, $H$, remaining constant. However, one thing I conceptually fail to grasp is why the pressure on gases that are expanding and compressing must be the same throughout? Suppose that $P_{2}$, the pressure on the left hand side, is greater than > $P_{1}$ the pressure on the right hand side. Suppose that our container walls are thermally isolated too. Then we compress the left hand side with a piston, slowly, letting gas through the nozzle, expanding the right hand side. See the diagram below. My reasoning comes down to $PV \propto nT$ for an ideal gas. Our volume on the LHS is decreasing. Let's say it decreases by a factor of 2. But since work is being done ON the gas, our temperature of the gas must increase, hence so must pressure too. Where have I gone wrong??

[image]

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the number of moles of gas on each side of the plug are constant.  Do you stand by that assumption?

Comment: Ah, no of course not as it's flowing through the nozzle. But how would you incorporate this into the maths to show pressure is constant. $PV \propto nT$ right?

Comment: Yes.  If P and T are constant, then V is proportional to n.

Comment: Yes, but without knowing P is constant a priori, how can one deduce P is constant? Furthermore, T can't be constant if we are looking at the volumes separate since work is being done ON the gas in volume 2 (RHS) FROM the gas in volume 1.

Comment: I thought you said you had mastered the mathematics of the open system version of the 1st law, and how it is applied to Joule Thomson;  if you had, you would know that the work you are referring to is included in the change in H.  P is constant because we apply constant pressures at the upstream and downstream sides.

Comment: I mean yes, I have, but I'm just not sure intuitively why P remains constant on the upstream and downstream, even though there's a change in volume, is that because we just make it to?

Comment: The molar volume does not change in the upstream channel and in the downstream channel.  It only changes within the porous plug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132711/discussion-between-jambajuice-and-chet-miller).